# Can reach URL from within docker container exec command, but Angular app gets ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: angular, docker, flask

Having issues accessing a Python/Flask back end via Angular application, both in Docker containers. This is done an an Ubuntu EC2 instance. When I utilize the exec command to sh into the Angular container, I am successfully able to reach the url using the docker internal host URL:

```
curl http://172.17.0.1:5000/employees/getAll
```

The URL calls the Flask service to get the data. But when the same call is done through the Angular app on that same container, I get an Unknown Error:

```
core.js:5828 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://172.17.0.1:5000/employees/getAll", ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://172.17.0.1:5000/employees/getAll: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://172.17.0.1:5000/employees/getAll"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Docker-Compose:

```
version: '3'
services:      
    angular:
        build: 
            context: ./angular-cluster/
        # volumes:
        #         - ./angular-cluster/:/app
        ports:
            - 80:4200

    cluster-db:
        build:
            context: ./cluster-db/
        network_mode: "host"
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
        volumes:
            - ./cluster-db/:/app
        environment:
            FLASK_APP: app.py
            FLASK_ENV: development
```

Angular Dockerfile

```
# base image
FROM node:latest

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

# add app
COPY . /app

ENV PATH ./node_modules/.bin:$PATH

RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9


EXPOSE 4200

# start app
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

Python/Flask Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH=$PATH:/app
ENV PYTHONPATH /app

#COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Answer (score 0):

the Angular aplication runs into the browser. Therefore you are outside the container. You must to make the request from your Angular app to the IP where the container is running. For example, if you are running docker in your PC the request must be to http://localhost:5000/employees/getAll.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding... Current process:


1. Hit ip-address that the angular app is hosted on the EC2

2. Angular app loads, calls http://172.17.0.1:5000/employees/getAll behind the scenes to get the data within the container (172.17.0.1 is the address to use from the container to reach the host URL, so instead of localhost)

3. Call fails

But when I go into the terminal of the container, the url is successful

Comment: Hi, you are running your application in two containers, an Angular application that is published on port 80 and a back-end published on port 5000. The angular app's container is serve as a static server. When you go to your app throught the browser you aren't in the container, you are outside it. Therefore the request must to be made to the IP where the backend's container is running, not to the internal IP of the container, and make sure that the API have the CORS enable.